# Synchronized multiple client connections to server

Tags: java, sockets, security, tcp, client-server

For one of our assignment we were asked to implement a ddos attack in java. The program states that a coordinater is connected to attackers (clients) and communicates to the attackers the time of the attack. The attackers then try to open simultaneous connections to the server as close to the specified time as possible. The server records the connections in a log file. My question is how would i be able to synchronize all the attackers into opening a connection at a specific time? I was looking inside the socket class and no such timed function exists. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Compute the number of milliseconds between now and the time of attack, sleep for this duration, and launch the attack. Or do the same and use a [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor%28%29) to schedule the attack.

Comment: I'd have the clients communicate their system time to the coordinator on startup (retrying if the initial sync fails), have the difference to the target date computed there, send a local target time back and sleep on the client until the system time reaches the target date. Extra points for computing the time you need for the three way handshake (roughly) and for using Quartz.

Comment: I would like to add that SO is there to help you with specific programming problems. You should at least show that you put some effort into solving this problem yourself. I can only speak for myself, but I tend to hate it to be treated as a free workforce. Showing no own effort may lead to this conclusion – for me, not in this case, hence my comment above. You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_.

Comment: Thank you both for the input. I'm sorry Markus if my question came out that way. I was thinking of using the network time protocol implementation but wanted to know if there was any other solution for this. I just joined this community and i didnt mean to offend anyone with my question but thanks for the pointer, i'll definitely give it a read!